# Understanding Android App certification

Tags: android, cordova, apk, android-keystore

I am slowly getting my head around the subject of Android app signing but each step I understand only leads to a further question.  What I have understood thus far (I should mention that my final objective is automating Phonegap builds on a headless Ubuntu server so everything I write below uses the Phonegap CLI)

> A keystore is a sequence of private-public key pairs each protected with their own password.  The keystore as a whole too has its own password. The *public* key **IS** the *certificate* that gets embedded in an APK. One can examine the certificate used in an APK as follows

- Unzip the APK (it is after all a ZIP archive)
- Grab the META-INF/CERT.DSA file
- keytool -list -file /path/to/CERT.DSA shows the certificate fingerprint.

> Generating public-private keypairs is easy. It can even be automated by issuing a simple

```
echo y | keytool -genkeypair -dname "cn=com.example, ou=OrgUnitName, o=Org Name, c=US" -alias ANY -keypass aliasPwd -keystore /path/to/keystore -storepass keyStorePwd -validity days
```

I built a *release* apk with Phonegap, sent myself a link to it via a text message, donwloaded and then installed the APK.  My phone gave me a few warnings but and then installed my APK.  Cool!.

But this set me wondering.... . I creaed a second alias

```
echo y | keytool -genkeypair -dname "cn=com.microsoft, ou=Microsoft Mobile, o=Microsoft, c=US" -alias msft -keypass msftPwd -keystore /path/to/keystore -storepass keyStorePwd -validity 9999
```

I rebuilt the APK this time with the Microsoft alias, sent myself a link to it and then downloaded and installed it (I have skipped a few installation details here).  My Android phone once again gave me a few warnings but did not seem overly concerned about my claims to being Microsoft.

I don't get it.  From what I have read in the Android world it is common practice to use self signed certificates.  So I have complete liberty to masquerade as microsoft.com or indeed anyone else?

The [Android Developer docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) state

> You should sign **all of your apps** with the same certificate throughout the expected lifespan of your applications.

So what happens if one day I sell the rights to one of my apps to someone else? That would either effectively force the buyer to start afresh with a new Android app or else I would be obliged to sell them everything, not just one app?

Clearly, all of the above are loopholes that are being dealt with effectively.  However, it is not at all clear to me what the measures to deal with them might be. I'd be most grateful to anyone who might be able to explain where my understanding and reasoning are flawed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I have complete liberty to masquerade as microsoft.com or indeed anyone else?

It's a self-signed certificate. Nobody pays attention to the values you use when generating the certificate, let alone believes them.

> The Android Developer docs state: "You should sign all of your apps with the same certificate throughout the expected lifespan of your applications."

As phrased, I would disagree with that assessment. Each app needs to be signed by the same certificate throughout the expected lifetime of each app. Whether multiple apps are signed by the same certificate is a business decision, as much as a technical one.

> So what happens if one day I sell the rights to one of my apps to someone else?

Um, yay?

> That would either effectively force the buyer to start afresh with a new Android app or else I would be obliged to sell them everything, not just one app?

This is why, if you anticipate that this might be something you want to do, you would use a separate certificate per app. Consultants definitely should do one certificate per app (or at least one per customer), for example.

Conversely, if you are building a suite of apps, where you specifically need for them to communicate between themselves securely, you might consider using a single certificate for all apps in the suite. The business ramification is that you would need to sell the rights in the suite as a whole.

Comment: OK.  But then where is the security?  In the browser world one relies on being able to trace SSL certs to a known CA that can be trusted. By and large browsers act as the watch dog and alert users to potential risks.  `self-signed cert. Nobody pays attention` but then who is protecting the interests of the hapless phone user?

Comment: @DroidOS: The self-signed certificate has two platform uses. First, the platform can determine if App A and App B were signed with the certificate, in which case they will have greater opportunity to work together than would two apps signed by different certificates (and therefore presumably are from different developers). Second, the platform if App A was signed by the same certificate that signed *the platform itself*, in which case App A can hold certain permissions (e.g., to reboot the device) that ordinary apps cannot.

Comment: @DroidOS: Apps can also inspect the public key portion of the certificate of another app, primarily to see if it matches a known value. Otherwise, the security in these self-signed certificates are about as good as the security in any use of self-signed certificates. For example, with the Web, a self-signed certificate is perfectly good for enabling SSL encryption, but is useless for establishing real-world identity or ties to some domain, which is why browsers warn users then such certificates are encountered.

Comment: thanks. You have clarified many issues but that in turn raises others. My understanding is that the **certificate** is the public key.  So a consultant type cannot simply use the one key store containing multiple key pairs used for different clients since he cannot just *give away* that keystore - if I understand right the SAME key can never be recreated. So he/she should have one keystore per client?

Comment: @DroidOS: "So he/she should have one keystore per client?" -- yes. "So a consultant type cannot simply use the one key store containing multiple key pairs used for different clients since he cannot just give away that keystore" -- there might be ways for **`keytool`** to extract a single key pair into its own keystore. I have never gone looking for it, but it wouldn't seem to be out of the question. That being said, I'd set up separate keystores per customer at the outset.

Comment: I am leaving this question open for a while longer to see what people have to say on the subject of Android security. I was living in blissful ignorance till I started my current keystore/signing research. Now I am starting to see that Android's signing + permissions system is about as bullet proof as a barn door. There is an interesting article on the subject [here](http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2015/08/waiting-for-androids-inevitable-security-armageddon/).

Comment: @DroidOS: That article has nothing to do with "Android's signing + permissions system".

Comment: Yes, it looks like I pasted the wrong URL.  Can't find the article that had so impressed me any more.